# How to implement OCR in website using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ocr, tesseract

I need to implement OCR (Optical character recognition) searching on my website using Laravel. How can I implement this in Laravel? Is this can be done only by open source OCR?

Any suggestion is appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: What is the OCR?

Comment: https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php  this might be useful. Take a look, study the basics and than try to build one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any php library for OCR but you can use Google or Amazon API for that.

I used Google Vision for one of my project and there result are good, not perfect but no one is.

Google Vision : https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Amazon Rekognition : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/rekognition/

Neutral comparison: https://cloudacademy.com/blog/google-vision-vs-amazon-rekognition/

Open Source tesseract project (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) can help you but i tried it with french language and the result are pretty bad and not acceptable for me

Answer (score 0):

i think tesseract-ocr or LaraOCR package can help you if you want try use it with simple words or text but if you need big convert big words must use google services or any big apis .